# Howto design the database/attribute numbers to keep database query overhaul at a minimum?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created routine Match, Team, etc models to create a soccer manager game and included many known statistics as attributes (total shots, shots wide, fouls, corners,..) in the Match model. I would like to give the statistics for each halftime. Therefore I created attributes like HomeTeamFirstHalfGoals and AwayTeamSecondHalfCorners. I plan to calculate the totals like

```
HomeTeamTotalGoals = HomeTeamFirstHalfGoals + HomeTeamSecondHalfGoals
```

within Match model and display some or all those stats as a LeagueTable when requested by the user. I suppose that the user may want to see different tables like all matches played within last week or whole fixture including some of the calculable attributes like TotalGoals etc. or the whole match list of a specific team/season.

However, the code is working too slowly. I do not know whether it is due to development environment and since I have little knowledge and more confusion about mysql, I wonder how I should design the match table.

The question is, (since I heard the notion of database query, which as I see, costs the server time and cpu) should I keep the number of attributes (like AwayTeamSecondHalfCorners) minimal and calculate the dependent ones (like TotalGoals) on the fly or do the opposite to keep overhaul at the server at a minimum?

Note: I suppose everyone knows that it is so easy to create a new column by typing A3=(A1+A2) in Excel. I am confused whether it is as easy as this in ruby views or it is more efficient to do it in the mysql table? Since I have no programming background, a guide to simple sources is welcome.

Comment: You should time what is slow. You can't skip that fase and ask a general question. Add timers and check where the problem lies. If it is a single query, then you might need to post that here and we can help you, it might just be something like a missing index. If its the amount of queries (so queries are quick, but there are infty of them) you might need to do smaller changes (like you randomly suggest with attributes) to make each query a tiny bit quicker. Without more knowledge, it is kinda hard to help ;)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Will "SQL> SET TIMING ON" do the work for me or should I sign up to not-all-that-free web services to time my queries?

Comment: Probably not worth going to a performance-measuring service just yet - I'd start with Benchmark or even something as simple as `start_time = Time.now; #code-in-question-goes-here; end_time = Time.now; duration_in_seconds = end_time - start_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways to approach this. First thing would be to start identifying which parts of your code are fast and which are not - I'd use Ruby's benchmark library ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html ).

In general, I'd recommend storing all the discrete data, and defining methods to calculate everything that can be derived from the discrete data. So, I'd say that a team's total goals would be something like:

```
def total_goals
  first_half_goals + second_half_goals
end
```

With whatever logic needs to be in place to do that math. Arithmetic like this is pretty fast and shouldn't cause any code complaints.

One thing that would cause big slowdowns is if your database is missing any indexes - any time you have a foreign key (typically anything that ends in _id; e.g., if a Game has an away_team_id and a home_team_id, then those are probably both foreign keys), there should be a corresponding index in your database. To add an index, create a new database migration, then drop in some code like this:

```
class AddIndexes < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_index :games, :home_team_id
    add_index :games, :away_team_id
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :games, :home_team_id
    remove_index :games, :away_team_id
  end

end
```

That'll speed up any time you're looking up the games that a team played by a very large margin.

Comment: So if "Arithmetic like this is pretty fast and shouldn't cause any code complaints." there is no problem to put attributes like CurrentGoals or CurrentFouls to individual players and teams, which are calculated and modified after each match (showing the total goals of a player or team scored during the whole season for example) and use these to populate and sort different kinds of tables. In other words there is no problem to over-populate the models with arithmetics like these, is that correct?

Comment: On the second look, home_team_id and away_team_id are actually just team_id but I cannot use team_id:references while creating the Match model, since the Match model should have home- and away team ids. So, since this "AddIndexes" is a joint table, if I'm not wrong, why cannot I simply put match_id and team_id only to Indexes?

Comment: AddIndexes isn't actually a joint table - what it's doing is adding indexes to the tables and fields you specify. It'd work just as well to say `add_index :games, :team_id`; the important part is that each table with foreign keys gets an index for each foreign key.

Comment: As to populating models with arithmetic, the arithmetic itself is very likely to be fine. The trouble you might run into is gathering the numbers to do the arithmetic on - if you're goign to have a `#current_goals` method on a player, adding up 150 values for all the games he's played is fast; gathering `Goals.where("scoring_player_id = ?", self.id)` might not be so quick. For values that have a lot of database lookups to handle, you might want to cache those as discrete elements in your database.

Comment: Thank you. As for Goals.where.. part, I'm not querying all the goals the player scored each time its looaked up. Instead, I'm updating the attribute after every match. As for AddIndexes, I noticed that it's not a joint table, but didn't deleted my comment, because I don't understand why there should be a home_team_id and away_team_id and hoped that maybe you could drop a line about that. I mean, why is there a need to further classify (subclass) the Team model. After all, both home and away_teams are teams. I suppose it's activerecord's mwthod to make two calls to the teams table. Any idea?

Comment: Well, I saw the attribute for HomeTeamTotalGoals, and thought that you might be tracking the away team and the home team for each game. It wouldn't require subclassing the Team model, it would just be a relationship - a game would have a home_team_id and an away_team_id, but both would point to a regular old Team object. I just kinda made an assumption about how things were being tracked - how do you keep track of which games a team plays as home and which games a team plays as away?

Comment: That's correct. When a team(user) selects another team for a match, I assign their respective ids as home or away_team_id depending on the location of the match. I am trying to refactor the code by minimizing the attributes (to minimize db queries) so wonder if this is the minimalist possible code(match having home and away_team ids, team having just id, some people suggest that team should have home and away_matches). Actually many-to-many relations need a guide better than provided in [RubyApi ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).